# Control.Arrow vs Data.Tuple.Extra

Tags: haskell

I often use the following functions of the `Data.Tuple.Extra` library: `first`, `second`, `***`, `&&&`, and `both`.

There are equivalent (?) functions in `Control.Arrow`. In fact I prefer `Data.Tuple.Extra` because I'm totally lost with the documentation of `Control.Arrow`.

Is there any advantage to use `Control.Arrow` (for example from a performance perspective)?

Comment: FWIW, `(&&&)` for functions is `liftA2 (,)`, using the function applicative. I don't feel it is worth it switching to that rather convoluted spelling just to avoid `Control.Arrow`, though.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with `Data.Tuple.Extra`, but from looking at the documentation, it seems to offer basically the same functionality as `Control.Arrow`. Its documentation even states:

> Some of these functions are available in the `Control.Arrow` module

You could easily implement the `dupe` and `both` functions using `Control.Arrow`:

```
dupe = id &&& id
both f = first f >>> second f
```

Examples:

```
Prelude Control.Arrow> dupe 42
(42,42)
Prelude Control.Arrow> both (+1) (41, 1336)
(42,1337)
```

Is there any advantage to using `Control.Arrow`? It's more general, since it's based on the `Arrow` type class, which again has its roots in category theory... Additionally, the module is included in the `base` package, so it's always available.

Being more general, the type of `both` defined here is `Arrow a => a d c -> a (d, d) (c, c)`, which means that you can use it with any `Arrow`, and not only with 'basic' functions. For instance, consider a `Kleisli` arrow.

The `print` function in the `Prelude` has the type `Show a => a -> IO ()`, and since `IO` is a `Monad`, you can make it a `Kleisli` instance, apply `both`, and run it on a pair:

```
Prelude Control.Arrow> runKleisli (both $ Kleisli print) (42, 1337)
42
1337
((),())
```

I don't know if this particular example is useful in real life, but it demonstrates that this implementation of `both` is more general.

---

BTW, pairs are also `Bifunctor` instances, so you can also use `first` and `second` from `Data.Bifunctor`. You can define `both` in terms of `Bifunctor` instead:

```
Prelude Data.Bifunctor> both f = bimap f f
Prelude Data.Bifunctor> :t both
both :: Bifunctor p => (a -> d) -> p a a -> p d d
Prelude Data.Bifunctor> both (+2) (40, 1335)
(42,1337)
Prelude Data.Bifunctor> both (*2) $ Right 21
Right 42
Prelude Data.Bifunctor> both (*2) $ Left 8
Left 16
```

Notice how, since this works on any `Bifunctor`, it works on `Either` in addtion to a pair.

You don't get `***` or `&&&` from `Data.Bifunctor`, though...

Comment: `(***)` for functions is `bimap` for tuples (sans the infixness).

Answer (score 2):

In most Haskell use cases, it doesn't matter whether you use `Data.Tuple.Extra.first`, `Control.Arrow.first` or `Data.Bifunctor.first` – all three will be used as

```
first :: (b -> c) -> (b,d) -> (c,d)
```

...and likewise for `second` / `***` / `&&&`. Both the `Arrow` and `Bifunctor` versions are more general, in different ways, but it's often quite possible to just think of the generalisation *in terms of* the standard tuple / functor case.

Pragmatically speaking, I'd suggest using the `Arrow` versions simply for the reason that they're in `base`. (Oh, I've just noticed `Bifunctor` is now in `base` too, so much for that...) Arguably, `Arrow` is also a better generalisation than `Bifunctor`, because it allows to actually leave the **Hask** category. Unfortunately, `Control.Arrow` itself doesn't really allow much more interesting categories – they largely boil down to Kleisli / Cokleisli categories (i.e. monads in different garment), and for those it's usually more practical to just stick to `do` notation etc..

But there are many maths categories that aren't instances of `Control.Category.Category`, because they don't allow mapping between *any* Haskell types but only types with particular properties. One example is **VectK**, the category of vector spaces with linear mappings as morphisms. In this category, `.` is matrix multiplication, `***` is block-matrix diagonal-stacking, `&&&` is vertical concatenation. Pretty nice IMO, in particular because it completely avoids the problems with runtime dimension checks you get in Matlab, NumPy or hmatrix – all that is already done by the compiler – and it even supports infinite-dimensional vector spaces.

The catch, as I said, is that it only works for particular types, which the standard `Category` / `Arrow` classes can't express. It is actually quite easy to express it in Haskell though, and so I have done with the [`constrained-categories` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories), used for implementing **VectK** in the [`linearmap-category` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category-0.3.4.0/docs/Math-LinearMap-Category.html).

Comment: My problem with `Control.Arrow` is that I don't understand the types. E.g. `arr :: (b -> c) -> a b c` What does it mean, `a b c` ? That's weird to me.

Comment: Read it as ``b `a` c``, which is usually simply `b -> c`.

Comment: Hmmm ok.. I'll try.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent FWIW, I read `a b c` as *an **a**rrow from **b** to **c***.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent One way I like to spell such types (though it's not a broadly recognised convention) is `arr :: Arrow y => (a -> b) -> y a b`. `y` is an unusual enough letter in signatures to make it stand apart -- and it even looks a bit pointy...

Comment: It would be nice to be able to give the type parameter an operator as a name: `arr :: Arrow (~>) => (a -> b) -> a ~> b`, that is: arr takes a *function* from `a` to `b` and turns it into an *Arrow* from `a` to `b`. They are arrows, after all, and should be notated as such.