# In functional programming, is there a name for a function that takes an x and gives back a tuple (x, x)?

Tags: functional-programming

I was wondering if there is a commonly used term for a function that turns a value into a tuple-2 in ML-family languages, or functional programming languages more generally?

```ml
let toTuple2 x = (x, x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the name of *that* specific function.

However, that function can be seen as a special case of a more general one:

```hs
let applyCtorToXX c x = c x x
```

Indeed, you can verify that `toTuple2` is equivalent to `applyCtorToXX (,)`.

In combinatory logic, or at least in how it is presented in [To Mock a Mockingbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Mock_a_Mockingbird), such a function is named a "[Warbler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warbler)", and the symbol `W` is used for it (i.e. `Wxy = xyy` is the definition used in the book).

Looking at it from this perspective, your `toTuple2` is `W (,)`, which is the application of a warbler to the 2-tuple constructor.

Answer (score 5):

In [stack-based programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming) such as Forth, `dup` is a core operator that does duplicate the top stack element (not exactly a tuple though).

In Haskell, [various packages provide](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=x%20-%3E%20(x%2Cx)) this function under names like `dup`, `dupe` or `double`. Notice that two-tuples are also a core element of arrows, and [`dup = id &&& id`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49231397/1048572).

I have not found anything specific to ML.